# How do I help Docker find Python 3.9 on my system?

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to build a rudimentary API and deploy it to a cloud environment with Docker. My API can be found in this directory here: [`https://github.com/n8feldman/cashman-flask-project`](https://github.com/n8feldman/cashman-flask-project). Basically, I've built a Flask API that can add "income" or "expense" items to an array through RESTful endpoints.

I downloaded Docker today and built the following Dockerfile in the root directory:

```
# Using lightweight alpine image
FROM python:3.6-alpine

# Installing packages
RUN apk update
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir pipenv

# Defining working directory and adding source code
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock bootstrap.sh ./
COPY cashman ./cashman

# Install API dependencies
RUN pipenv install

# Start app
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/bootstrap.sh"]
```

I then run the command `docker build -t cashman .` from the root directory of my project and get the following output:

```
[+] Building 1.1s (11/11) FINISHED                                                                                                                            
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.6-alpine                                                                                     0.3s
 => [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.6-alpine@sha256:579978dec4602646fe1262f02b96371779bfb0294e92c91392707fa999c0c989                               0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 1.01kB                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [2/7] RUN apk update                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [3/7] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir pipenv                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [4/7] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [5/7] COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock bootstrap.sh ./                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [6/7] COPY cashman ./cashman                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [7/7] RUN pipenv install                                                                                                                       0.7s
------                                                                                                                                                        
 > [7/7] RUN pipenv install:                                                                                                                                  
#11 0.607 Warning: Python 3.9 was not found on your system...                                                                                                 
#11 0.608 Neither 'pyenv' nor 'asdf' could be found to install Python.                                                                                        
#11 0.608 You can specify specific versions of Python with:
#11 0.608 $ pipenv --python path/to/python
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pipenv install]: exit code: 1
```

How can I decipher the error message at the bottom and fix the issue?

Comment: `FROM python:3.6-alpine` Your Dockerfile is using Python 3.6, not 3.9.

Comment: Ah. That seems to have fixed the issue. But why is it requiring python3.9 to run pipenv install - does python deprecate so fast that pipenv can no longer work with relatively recent versions of python 3?

Comment: It might be relevant that my computer is running version 3.9.6 and I did my installations and build my virtual environment with that version, so perhaps I cannot create a docker image with an earlier version now that I've already built the application with something more advanced?

Comment: Why do you want to install pipenv in the first place? In the container there is no need to do that if you have only that app in it, imo.